# Ionic Package Build Android failed - dont understand error message

Tags: android, cordova, build, ionic-framework, package

This is the error message:

```
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device" via npm
shell.js: internal error
Error: ENOSPC, no space left on device '/home/package/workspace/apps-483d2a0c-2/cordova/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/src/blackberry10'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:747:18)
    at cpdirSyncRecursive (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:58:8)
    at cpdirSyncRecursive (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:73:7)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:180:9
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object._cp (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:157:11)
    at Object.cp (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
    at copyPlugin (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:289:15)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/fetch.js:159:27
```

working on cloud9. tried to package simple app.

Command was:

```
ionic package build android
```

can someone explain me what this error means?

Answer (score 0):

The error means there is no space left on your disk (in cloud9).

Comment: this is an service from ionic to build the app on their servers. i fixed the issue by removing "ionic-platform-web-client". But i don't get it ^^

Comment: Well, the folder it tries to write to (on the server) is apparently full. Try clearing the /tmp folder?

Comment: Should be possible with `$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/*​` https://community.c9.io/t/how-do-i-clear-up-disk-space-after-its-full/213

Comment: Ok, I have the same problem now... also using the Ionic Cloud package service - local disk has 50 gigs free). Did you ever figure it out? - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-package-ios-release-build-error-in-package-ionic-services/109507/9